# phpmyadmin 500 Internal Server Error after sudo a2enmod rewrite

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I configure my server for Laravel app with the composer. this is installation process:

1. apache2
2. PHP
3. MariaDB
4. phpmyadmin

until here the `phpmyadmin` works. but after Laravel installation and specially using `sudo a2enmod rewrite` for registering VirtualHost, I get the 500 internal server error on `phpmyadmin`. whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check error here the : `nano /var/log/apache2/error.log`

In my Case Error was **.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled**

**Solution** :

```
sudo a2enmod headers
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```